# FocusEvent Timing - Race Condition?

Tags: java, events, user-interface, swt, race-condition

**Can race conditions occur between SWT focusGained and focusLost events?**

If one has multiple text field that all have events for when focus is both gained and lost, what is the timing of the events if one moves directly from one text field to another?  Will they trigger is a specific order (focusLost on the previous field, then focusGained on the next), or is the order unpredictable?

Comment: Order will be predicable. focusLost, then focusGained

Comment: @ControlAltDel This would make a good answer, provided you can cite evidence.  Do you have any information to cite?  I have been unsuccessful in finding any such documentation myself.

Comment: Looking at the SWT source, for Mac OS X it appears to definitely be FocusOut followed by FocusIn. For the Linux/GTK source it appears to be whatever order GTK generates the events in (may be the same, I don't know).

Comment: @greg-449 I was hoping that there would be some sort of documentation that would clearly define this one way or another (I'm not specifically asking for a resource, but it definitely wouldn't hurt).  Is it just stated somewhere in some sort of specifications?